# Why is MS Excel Power Query sending multiple requests to Olingo V4 spring boot service

Tags: powerquery, olingo, odata-v4, double-redirect

I have used the Olingo library to expose Odata endpoint. Goal is to access /odata/models endpoint from any tool or Excel power Query. However, when the call is from Excel Power Query I see two requests being fired for the same endpoint one after the other. This doesn't happen when I try the same endpoint from Postman. I want to know if anyone has ever seen this happening while using Olingo Odata V4 with spring boot when called from Excel? It is a bit of a performance concern as each call strikes the database.

I tried debugging but just not able to analyse if an internal call causes this or if excel is making this double calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this doesn't exactly address your Olingo Odata V4 application, this is a very general purpose explanation of why it is happening. Privacy checks, column profiling, caching results, connector design, etc could all cause multiple hits to the same source within the same query.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/multiple-queries

I hope this helps understand or direct further research.

Comment: yes, that makes quite the sense. Thanks for the information. Probably I need to dig deep and find out what exactly causes those double requests from Power Query in this particular scenario.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I have the same issue using SQL Server. Both are from Microsoft.